# Assigning the value of the sender object to a variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm using several comboboxes from which I have to extract values and concatenate them in a textbox.
The problem is that I use `sender.get_selectedItem().Get_value();` to extract the data of each one, each one that obtains the data of a combobox, all the variables acquire the same value (it does not keep the values obtained in the previous variable), I am using Telerik controls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CMP(sender, eventArgs {

        if (document.getElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceholder_rgpartesRFQ_ctl00_ctl05_planta")) {

            var pl = sender.get_selectedItem().get_value();

            var fo = sender.get_selectedItem().get_value();

            var gr = sender.get_selectedItem().get_value();

            var di = document.getElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceholder_rgpartesRFQ_ctl00_ctl05_txtdiam1").value;

            var lo = document.getElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceholder_rgpartesRFQ_ctl00_ctl05_Txtlongt").value;

            var codemp = document.getElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceholder_rgpartesRFQ_ctl00_ctl05_txtcmp").value;

            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceholder_rgpartesRFQ_ctl00_ctl05_txtcmp").value = "M" + pl + fo + gr + di + lo;
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceholder_rgpartesRFQ_ctl00_ctl02_ctl04_planta").value !== null) {

        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What makes you assume "sender.get_selectedItem().get_value()" will return a different value each time you call it? If the selected item doesn't change, nor will the value. You're not changing the selected item between the three calls to get_value so the value will be the same. Are you trying to get all selected items from the combobox?

Comment: Yes, I tried to get them in multiple ways and this is the one that gives me a value, so I want it when I get a value stop and get the following.